# Look up table allowing null

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an `incident` table that has an `incidentTypeId(int)` that is a foreign key allowing null.

The `incidentType` table has two columns `Id auto increment primary key not null` and `incidentType not null nvarchar`.

The `incidentType` table is for populating a `DDL` i have a `listItem` that is selected as the `selected` and a value of "". I am checking if the value is "" and if it is I am setting the `selectedValue` of my `DDL` to null.

When I select something from the `DDL` everything is fine and works ok.

When I try and `insert` with nothing selected and it is set to `null` I get a `sqlexception on foreign key constraint` on the `incidentType Id` column not allowing null as it is the primary key .

How can I get round allowing null?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are doing the Insert, perhaps you need to also do a check for `IsNullOrEmpty` on that DDL and make sure that if nothing is selected that you perhaps pass in a Null value or empty string to be inserted..

Comment: I am using `Linq`                 db.tblIncidents.InsertOnSubmit(incident);
                db.SubmitChanges();

Comment: You say it is `Id auto increment` which means it should increment itself without you needing to have it in your `INSERT` statement

Comment: @DavidStarkey yes that is my look up table my Incident table is just holds the incidentTypeId allowing null type `int`

Comment: can you show the code.. for that particular process the Method or event where you are Invoking the code.. I am also wondering if you have some `constraints` setup improperly on the Database side `incidentType` this line is what I am thinking is causing the issue if it states `not null nvarchar` then you would get an Error if nothing is set you need to pass in a value perhaps string.Empty would do Show the Insert Statement that would be most Helpful

Comment: if (drp_Type_Of_Incident.SelectedValue == "")
                {
                    SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentType = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentType = drp_Type_Of_Incident.SelectedValue;  
                }

Comment: Read your Question again you are stating thta IncidentType allows for null but in your question you state the following `The incidentType table has two columns Id auto increment primary key not null and incidentType not null nvarchar` `not null means` it `Expects a value`

Comment: Can you write your `INSERT` command to the console or screen and then show us?  Feel free to edit any sensitive info if need be.

Comment: The `Incident` Table allows a `null` field for the `incidentTypeID` sorry I will edit the question.

Comment: My insert command: just creates a new `tblIncident` and assigns the `incidentTypeId` = `Convert.ToInt32(SessionVars.Current.Incident.incidentType)`

Comment: Edit your question and just post the relevant code.  That is where the problem almost certainly is, and failure to post it is why people keep down-voting you.

Comment: We need all relevant code because there is a major communication break down.  Please post any errors and/or exceptions also.  We need both C# and the sql queries in question.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key cannot be Null. It is not possible as your entry must have an ID number. Otherwise there is noting to create.